# Why must be objects initialized in onCreate?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView number=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.number2);
TextView number2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.number2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    number.setText("Text");
    number.setText("Text");
}
```

followed by more code, but when I run it it crashes.

After doing that i tried to initialize TextViews in onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView number;
TextView number2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    number=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.number);
    number2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.number2);
    number.setText("Text");
    number.setText("Text");
}
```

and it worked. Why must objects be initialized in onCreate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your activity won't have a `Window` until `onCreate()`. Attempting to find any views before the window is initialized will lead to NPE.

Additionally, attempting to find views before `setContentView()` will return `null`s and so the return values are not good for anything.